# Convert Fecha to Calendar

Tags: java, calendar

Fecha is my class customize. I can convert Caledar to Fecha with this method:

```
public Fecha(Calendar fecha) {
    this.day = fecha.get(Calendar.DATE);
    this.month = fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    this.year = fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

However I can't convert Fecha to Calendar:

```
public Calendar fechaToCalendar(Fecha f) {
    Calendar c = null;

    return c;
}
```

How I can do ?

Comment: Why not? What is going wrong? Please elaborate.

Comment: By writing proper code. Here is [reference of `java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

Comment: I don´t know to do this method for convert Fecha to Calendar.

Comment: `c = new GregorianCalendar();` ... `c.set(Calendar.MONTH, fecha.month + 1);` ... Got the idea? ...

Answer (score 0):

the solution:

```
public static Calendar fechaToCalendar(Fecha f) {
    Calendar c = null;
    c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.set(Calendar.DATE, f.day);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, f.month - 1);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, f.year);
    return c;
}
```